# Void recursive reverse method for Strings

Tags: java, string, recursion, reverse, void

I have seen a lot of questions on here about recursive reverse methods for strings with the answer that they should add String as a parameter. For an assignment, the method must be void. This is what I have and "String next = other + firstChar;" is erroring because it can not combine the two types since "other" is a Sentence variable. How can I structure it to be able to add them?

```
public void reverse()
{
   //implement a recursive method
   if (text.isEmpty()){
         return;
   }
   else 
   {
       char firstChar = text.charAt(0);
       String otherCharacters = text.substring(1, text.length());
       Sentence other = new Sentence(otherCharacters);
       other.reverse();
       String next = other + firstChar;
       text = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Provided `Sentence.toString()` does something vaguely sensible: `other.toString() + firstChar` or `"" + other + firstChar`.

Comment: (BTW, this is a really awkward way to reverse a string)

Comment: Haha I realize it is a weird way, but it is the structure my professor suggested. If you know of another way to do it that is still void, please let me know. @AndyTurner

Comment: `text = new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString();`.

Comment: You don't understand it, and it works, but is it allowed? For an assignment it's rarely allowable to use built-in/library methods. I also wonder how you're using "void" — a void method is one that doesn't return anything, but you seem to be using the word like it means "doesn't take any parameters". `public void main(String... args)` is a _void_ method, even though it accepts parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, how `Sentence` class has been implemented, a sample recursive void may look like this:

```
static String reversed = "";
static String input = "String to reverse";
static int pos = 0;

static void reverse() {
    if (pos == input.length()) {
        return;
    } 
    reversed += input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - pos++);
    reverse();
}
```